# How copy or save Lint warnings in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

When using Ctrl C (on Windows) the Lint warnings in my Android project are not copied to clip board. There is no button to save. How can I copy or save the Lint warnings in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the text editor window, move your cursor on the yellow/red label on the right for a while, and a floating window will display the complete message. Click on it and you can select the message contents.
2. In the "Problems" menu tab, you can right click on every warning/error item and select to copy them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a separate project to export Eclipse markers (like warnings or errors). http://suppresswarnings.drupalgardens.com/